# Based on the drop down value selected I have to retrieve other values from database in c#

Tags: c#

I have 2 drop down list which is category and product name. I am able to populate values in the product name list based on the category selected. Now I have to populate other fields like price and available quantity from database based on the product name selected.

This is code for category drop down

```
             private void makerOrderFrm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
             {
               string selectCommand = "select distinct(productCategory) from  
               productsTbl";
                 try
                 {
                    conn.Open();
                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectCommand, conn);
                 SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                cmbCategory.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
            }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("can't show categories");

        }
```

This is code for product name drop down list

```
            private void cmbCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(objectsender, 
            EventArgs e)
            {
             conn.Close();
           cmbProdName.Items.Clear();
            string selectCommand2 = "select productName from productsTbl 
            where productCategory=@productCategory";
           try
           {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectCommand2, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productCategory", 
           cmbCategory.Text);
             SqlDataReader reader = 
            cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                cmbProdName.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
            //cmbCategory.SelectedIndex = 0;
            reader.Close();
            }
             catch (SqlException)
             {
            MessageBox.Show("can't show categories");

               }
              }
```

Now I'm unable to fetch fields like price,available quantity based on the product name selected

```
                private void cmbProdName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
               EventArgs e)
               {

                string selectCommand2 = "select productPrice,productQuant 
               from productsTbl where productName=@productName";

                try
                 {
                  conn.Open();
                  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectCommand2, conn);
                  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productPrice", 
                   txtProductPrice.Text);
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productQuant", 
                    txtAvblQty.Text);


                     }
                   catch (SqlException)
                       {
                     MessageBox.Show("can't show categories");

                         }
                         }
```

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? Is it a SqlException? Is the data not being brought correctly?

Comment: Your command requires productName as a parameter. However, you're not passing productName, you're passing productPrice and productQuant which are not required. And I don't see where you execute the command

Comment: Based on the category selected, I am able to fetch product name list.

Comment: But when I select a value from product name list the price and quantity should be fetched which is not happening